# React-router and Link in server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I'm converting a react app to be rendered server-side.

I have things like this:

`import React from 'react'
import R, { Link } from 'react-router'
console.log("router:", R) // R is undefined!
class C1 extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (<Link to="/somewhere">somewhere</Link>)
  }
}`

That used to work, but now `react-router` is undefined on the server. I have installed it: `npm install --save react-router`, version ^4.2.0.

How would I make links work with server- and client-side react? I know I can do this: `import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'` and use NavLink instead of Link. However, this results in a server-side call on every click of a link. I'd like client-side react to use perhaps pushstate and not refer to the server after the initial load.

Answer (score 0):

try to add to npm `npm install -g react-router-dom` then `import { BrowserRouter, Link, Route, Router, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';`

the code will be:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Link, Route, Router, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

<BrowserRouter>
  <Link to='/' >Home</Link>
  <switch>
    <Route path='/' exact render={(props) => <`your component` />}>
  </switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: This is the same behavior as before: clicking on the <Link /> issues a request that's answered by the server. I'd like it to cause a pushstate event that changes state of client only, without touching the server.